# External Interrupts, Mega2560

Tags: arduino-mega, atmel

I have a question for you guys. I have some code that triggers an ultra-sonic sensor to measure distance. My code uses the EICRB register and executes in interrupt when it sees a transition on the interrupt pin. The interrupt routine is supposed to calculate the time of the echo pulse that comes from the sensor. The width of the pin is proportional to the distance measured.

I'm not sure why I'm not getting great results. There seems to be a persistent error in my measurement and I'm not sure why. It's probably something stupid. Here's a screenshot of the code I have if anyone can lend some help. Thanks for reading.

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post a screenshot of your code, post the code itself. It's way easier to copy-paste (which is useful for testing).

Comment: What do you mean with "persistent error"? Please be more specific

Comment: Yea sorry, what I mean is the measurement seems to be off by a fixed amount. Whether the sensor is 10cm or 50cm away from an object, there's some error quantity that is fixed. the shorter the distance, the larger a proportion the error is. Longer distance gives smalled error.

Comment: How large of an error?